# Apache Kafka Cassandra Connector cassandra query overhead [lenses.io]

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect

I know Lenses.io has a kafka cassandra connector. But when using cassandra as a source it is using "Allow Filtering".
I know "Allow Filtering" increases cassandra load, I am worried this will increase the load on my cassandra cluster.

Please advise.

I am using timestamp as clustering key that is being used in the query. [Partition key is not being used]

Comment: do you mean to use Cassandra as source?

Comment: yes thanks @AlexOtt, correct in my use case i am using cassandra as a source.